# Build multiple react native bundles from one source

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, react-native, ecmascript-6

For example I have React Native application with some features. The most complete application contain

1. News
2. Products
3. User authorization

I want to have 2 builds. Like "**free**" and "**pro**" version.

Let's say **Free** contain only News. And **Pro** contain all features. How can I build it and do NOT include imports of features, that I don't need.

In my mind I have something like:

```
if (ENV === 'free') {
   import Products from 'products';
}
```

But you know, that module **import** always should be on top of file and can't be wrapped by `if-else` or anything else. And at all looks not very good.

So any ideas? Or maybe it's already present common practice for doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the app is built with Webpack, usually it is as simple as having separate entry points that have imports for environment-dependent module (`Product`) and common denominator (everything else).

`import` can't be conditional, but underlying modular API can. It can be

```
let Products;

if (ENV === 'pro') {
   Products = require('products').default;
} else {
   Products = null;
}
```

Webpack also supports [dynamic `require`s](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) (`ContextReplacementPlugin` can be likely used as well):

```
Products = require(`./${ENV}/products`).default;
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your application is structured I think, one approach is doing on component level (with the ifs):

```
render() or constructor() {
...

  if(env === 'PRO') {
    ... unlock all the awesome features
  }
}
```

Another option is doing it on routing level, which still contains if/elses and might require bigger architectural challenges on component level (having the 2 versions of the same components, one pro, one free), but with the benefit of having the ENV dependency in a single file

```
<Routes >
  <Route path="/list" component={env=='PRO'? ProList: FreeList}/>
</Routes>
```

The other option is restructuring your application into two codebases and importing them depending on the build, similar to platform specific code, something along the lines of:

files:

`list.pro.js`

`list.free.js`

and on index.js:

```
import proList from 'list.pro';
import freeList from 'list.free';

// Global var or store it somewhere
List = env === 'PRO'? proList : freeList;
```

My approach would be decomposing the app as much as possible, try to minimize the amount of `ifs` but include them on component level.

Comment: But in your solution proList and freeList anyway will be included in built bundle?

Comment: Without any changes in the Webpack configuration yes, if you really don't want this you can try to play around with webpack configuration, pull the files to bundle from different folders, that would be a fourth option, but not sure this is entirely possible.

Comment: I heard about "tree shaking". Will try to dig in this way. Thank you :)

Answer (score -3):

The one way is you can comment that piece of code which is not required in first build and run bundle command from project home dir.

Make another bundle by uncommenting the required code.

Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, nice solution if you write "Hello world" app. But for large project I want to have it automated.. So thinking how better do it

Comment: This is not real solution to the problem, its error-prone and inconsistent